# Virtualizing Uniformgrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Does anyone know if there exists a virtualizing uniformgrid implementation somewhere for WPF that one can use?

I've tried one stackoverflow and Google and found nothing so far.

What I have been using so far is a ListBox with a UniformGrid as its ItemsPanel. But that doesn't virtualize.

Answer (score 1):

Yes virtualization is tricky for grids and dockpanels and currently no such control exists in WPF.

But there are a few options...

1. if you want know how to make a virtualized tile panel (more like a uniform grid and wrappanel) then see this... http://blogs.msdn.com/dancre/archive/2006/02/06/implementing-a-virtualized-panel-in-wpf-avalon.aspx
2. Otherwise xamDataPresenter can pretty much act like a virtualized uniform grid (see XamDataCard ) and wrap panel. Its 3rd party control though belonging to Infragistics ...

Answer (score 1):

The closest I got yesterday was this [VirtualizingTilePanel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VirtualTilePanelFillMod.aspx) inspired by Dan Creviers work. Sadly it dropping it in as a repacement for uniformgrid didn't just work out of the box.