# Is there any way to make sure unifromgrid re-render its items at and only at the end of its resize

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, uniformgrid

I start learn wpf recently and I found that uniformgrid has bad performance, it will recalculate and re-render it's items on resize triggered(like window resize or itself resized), this will make application really lag (eg: when retract sidebar animation played), I think that it's because of it call `ArrangeOverride` too frequently, so I try to delay re-render until resize end, if it happens in `SizeChanged` event then I can capture resize ends and block re-render task until then, but it's happened in `ArrangeOverride` and I don't know how to handle it

Comment: What you are looking for is some type of virtualization for uniform grid.  The datagrid control has this but it is not built into uniform grid.  Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874041/virtualizing-uniformgrid)

Comment: actually I didn't means virtualizing, I have impl a virtualizing uniformgrid myself, where the question is that uniform grid need re-render it every time size changes, like it can contains 4 items per row before size change and 5 items after size change, then uniform grid would calculate and resize it to "uniform", but the resize it real time, what I want to do is like some "resize end event", before resize ends the uniform grid won't re-render, and when resize ends there have a event to notify the uniformgrid that "resize has ended so you can re-render now"

Comment: my problem is kind like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809752/resize-a-winform-window-only-when-resize-end) but this is resize a winform window and it is triggered manually, what I need is detect size changed triggered by animation or neighbor controls's size changed besides trigger it manually